# NSUnknownKeyException even though saveButton outlet is defined

Tags: ios, swift

I have a save button defined on a navigation bar controller. 
This is connected in the viewController.swift file as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

The button has no other outlets as depicted below:

[image: Referencing Outlets]

Yet when I run the program I get the following error:

Thread 1: Exception: "[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key saveButton."

No other view controller on my story board is implementing the custom view controller where i've defined the outlet.

All other threads on why this error is thrown point me towards removing broken outlets but I don't believe I have any.

Comment: check if your `viewController ` class is property connected to that in storyboard, could it be ViewController with capital V? The problem is in class's connection to its storyboard, not the outlet itself.

Comment: The value under class name in the identity inspector when highlighting the view, matches the class name defined in the swift file. Could it be something to do with the view controller being embedded in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Fixed by checking the box to inherit the module from the target